# php session flash message

Tags: php, session, controller

i'm tryning to create session flash message after redirection.

i have Controller class

```
class Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
    if(!empty($_SESSION['FLASH']))
        foreach($_SESSION['FLASH'] as $key => $val)
        $this->$key = $val;
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $_SESSION['FLASH']=null;
    }
}
```

also i have Controller child class Home, where functions are run by route, like /Home/Index  => public function index()

```
class Home extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //where i want to display $this->message only once
        echo $this->message; // but $this->message is undefinded why? 
    }
    public function Post_register(){
        //after post form data
        // validation 

        // this function redirect to /Home/Index  above function index();
        Uri::redirectToAction("Home","Index",array('message' => 'some message'));
    }
}
```

and uri class function where i redirecting user.

```
public static function redirectToAction($controller,$method,$arr)
{
    $_SESSION['FLASH'] = $arr;
    header("Location:/".$controller.'/'.$method);
}
```

but `$this->message` is undefinded why?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: Where do you set `$this-message`?  If you don't set it anywhere it will be undefined.

Comment: Do you have session_start() function call somewhere in your code? 
php manuel on sessions_start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: i'm tyinig to create my own framework,
here: $this->$key = $val;
yes i have session_start();

Comment: What version of php do you use?

Comment: @Nico  php version : 5.4.7

Comment: I answered similar question here [wordpress-best-way-to-use-flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860374/wordpress-best-way-to-use-flash-messages-for-front-end-users/57007325#57007325 ) check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your __destruct. 
When the execution is finished, __destruct function is called and it unset your $_SESSION['FLASH'] therefore, it is no longer accessible in your script.

[From the php manuel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

Just remove your __destruct function.

Comment: oh thanks @Nico, it's working now :)  i was thinking remove session in destructor but it was wrong.

    if(!empty($_SESSION['FLASH']))
    foreach($_SESSION['FLASH'] as $key => $val)
    $this->$key = $val;
    
    unset($_SESSION['FLASH']);

this working now :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided `$message` is never defined as a member of the `Controller` class or its derived class `Home`. If you want to use that member variable you have to declare it as a member of the class, I.E. `public $message` and then set it somewhere in execution, presumably in your `Uri::redirectToAction` function.

Comment: yes defined  by this code
if(!empty($_SESSION['FLASH']))
        foreach($_SESSION['FLASH'] as $key => $val)
        $this->$key = $val;
    }

if i remove destruct its working, but i want to display this message only once, then remove session

Comment: @GiaNebieridze Then why don't you just `unset()` the session variables in the foreach loop in your constructor once your reset set the class member instead of using a destructor?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library just for this type of projects https://github.com/tamtamchik/simple-flash.

Once you have it installed you can do this.

In your `redirectToAction`:

```
public static function redirectToAction($controller,$method,$arr)
{
    flash($arr['message']);
    header("Location:/".$controller.'/'.$method);
}
```

And in `index`:

```
public function index()
{
    echo flash()->display(); 
}
```

It'll generate [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) friendly alert messages.