# how to use javascript in php when there is a header?

Tags: javascript, php

```
if(($row["status"])!="valid")
{
    $stats=$row["status"];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Your Status is $stats..Please Try Again Later...');";
    echo "</script>";
    header ("location: index.php");
}
```

it is a part of a php code. if i use // before header, javascript run..but when i don't use // , it goes to directly index.php. what is the solution?? OR is there is any way that i can call a javascript function for showing a message from this if condition??

Comment: Because you can't send output with headers, and you're echoing three times instead

Comment: why you are trying something like a `session flash message` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748240/php-session-flash-message

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, Replace header with **`document.location.href`** So you can display an alertbox and when you click ok it redirects to your index.php page

```
if(($row["status"])!="valid")
{
    $stats=$row["status"];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Your Status is $stats..Please Try Again Later...');";
    echo "</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: @mishir.ali If it's working and you're through, you should accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
        <?php 
            if(isset($row["status"]) && trim($row["status"])!="valid")
            {
                    $stats=$row["status"];
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
                    echo "alert('Your Status is $stats..Please Try Again Later...');";
                    echo "window.location.href='index.php';"; // instead php header you can use javascript location.hrfe 
                    echo "</script>";                           
            }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try

if(($row["status"])!="valid")
{
$stats=$row["status"];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Your Status is $stats..Please Try Again Later...');";
echo "</script>";
}
else{
header ("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: This looks different than what OP wants, the redirect should happen after the alert, not _instead of_

Comment: what should be your o/p? this code will work if conition is true and show the alert and if the condition is false you will redirect to the header page.

Comment: Of course this code will work, but it's **not** what OP wants to do! Read the question again and have a look at the other answers and comments

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this

```
if(($row["status"])!="valid")
{
$stats=$row["status"];
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Your Status is $stats..Please Try Again Later...');";
echo "location: index.php";
echo "</script>";
}
```